# Chrome CPU spike but cannot reproduce when DevTools is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory, google-chrome-devtools, cpu

I found a weird bug on a website page that requires an account to see unfortunately. When I open this page, Chrome CPU usage spikes and the page doesn't load but when I access the page with the DevTools open everything works fine.

Any idea why that is ?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. See if it's ok in Canary or [the latest Chromium](https://download-chromium.appspot.com). Also try finding the last version of Chrome when it worked using the [bisect-builds script](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py).

Comment: It's a rendering bug since it works when DevTools is open thanks to the smaller page width but when I extend the window I get the same freeze. Might be a css media query or something like that...

Comment: Without being able to inspect and analyze what is happening, we can only make blind guesses.  Based on the information available, this isn't answerable, I'm afraid.